# Not able to execute a FileUpload program in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, single-page-application

I am not able to upload a file using NodeJS and getting following exception.

**Exception:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
    at c:\nital\my-data\my-sample-apps\nodejs\tutorialspoint-samples\Sample37.js:22:26
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\nital\my-data\my-sample-apps\nodejs\tutorialspoint-samples\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (c:\nital\my-data\my-sample-apps\nodejs\tutorialspoint-samples\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (c:\nital\my-data\my-sample-apps\nodejs\tutorialspoint-samples\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:52:37)
    at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:431:18)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:374:17)
```

I googled on this and found that the `req.files` API is no longer available in Express 4 framework which is mentioned at http://expressjs.com/api.html#req

Since I am quite new to NodeJS not sure how to fix this. Can somebody guide? My actual program is listed below.

**FileUploadDemo.js**

```
//Express framework demo. File Upload demo
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
var upload = multer({dest: 'C:/tmp/'});

app.get('/upload.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "upload.html");
});

//uploading the file here
//app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files.file.name);
    console.log(req.files.file.path);
    console.log(req.files.file.type);

    var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;
    fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                response = {
                    message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                    filename: req.files.file.name
                };
            }
            console.log(response);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used `upload.single()`, the file is accessible through `req.file`  and not `req.files.file`. If you have multiple files uploaded (`upload.array()` or something) then it will be accessible with `req.files`.

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked but it uploads the file with a different name. For example, I uploaded the file `test.txt` and it uploaded the file  with name `5b6c3f0bb972901306dc712e8c9e1ba7` and does not have an extension either. When I try to open that file in a text editor it shows some weird characters.

Comment: Just rename it (you can use `fs.rename()` ), you can access the `file.originalname` property to get the .. original name :P